# Display custom field outside the loop

Tags: custom-field, loop

Inside of my WordPress theme directory I have a standalone PHP file called image, this currently looks like this....

```
<?php
  define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
  require('/home/mysite/public_html/wp-blog-header.php');
?>

<?php
  global $post;
  $post_id = 288;
  $header_image = get_post_custom_values('caption', $post_id);
    echo get_post_meta($post_id, 'caption', true);
?>
```

When I visit this site I want it to return the custom field value for 'caption' but I am getting nothing.  I realise this page is outside of the loop but I thought I have included the wp-blog-header.php that it needed.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to *accomplish*? You've provided us with an *implementation*, but no context regarding *why* you're trying to use this particular implementation. If we know what you're ultimately trying to accomplish, we can probably provide a much better answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
  define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
  require('wp-blog-header.php');
?>

<?php
    $post_id = 288;
    echo get_post_meta($post_id, 'caption', true);
?>
```

That part is enough - are you sure that this is the name of your custom field and the path to wp-blog-header is resolved and valid?